# Нужна ли запятая после «не знаю»?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение, как

***Не знаю** как ты, а я не хочу быть съеденной.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Не знаю, как ты, а я не хочу быть съеденной.***

Запятая перед придаточным предложением (перед "как") **ставится**.
[Я] Не знаю, как ты [считаешь, думаешь], а я не хочу быть съеденной.

> Если придаточное предложение состоит из одного только союза или союзного слова, запятая перед ним не ставится: *Не знаю **как**. Не помню **когда**.*
>
> [№ 287724](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&mode=spravka)
> Не знаю как вы, но я воспринимаю эти стихи буквально. Нужна ли запятая перед "как вы"? Я считаю, что запятая не нужна.
> ОТВЕТ
> Запятая ставится (разделяет части сложного предложения).

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса

• ***Не знаю, как ты,** а я хочу домой вернуться* (Дина Сабитова. Где нет зимы).

• ***Не знаю, как ты,** а я счастлива!* (Ирина Безладнова. Такая женщина).

• ***Не знаю, как ты,** а я надеюсь только на свои силы* (Андрей Лазарчук. Все, способные держать оружие...).

[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)